# What is the default http user agent header sent by the .NET SoapClient class?

Tags: c#, http, soap, wse

What is the default http user agent header sent by the .NET SoapClient class?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I know how to find the answer. Enable System.Net trace source and look at the headers it sends. [Using System.Net Tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2005/09/18/471003.aspx)

Comment: For any who do not know, `SoapClient` is part of the obsolete WSE product, and should not be used unless there is no other choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if you still need this, but...

My default is:

> User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client
>   Protocol 4.0.30319.1)

Answer (score 1):

User Agent:

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.1)

Mozila = Default Browser 4.0 = Version for Default Browser MSIE = Microsoft Internet Explore 6.0 = Version of Microsoft Internet Explorer Default Text = Web Service Client Protocol (Editable in web service) 4.0.30319.1 = Version of CLR (Editable in web service)